# Why is WebGL frame rate dropping in full screen?

Tags: performance, google-chrome, webgl, rendering

I'm rendering a somewhat complex WebGL scene [here](https://tuzz.tech/webgl-demo/). When I view the scene on my MacBook Pro's built-in display in full screen it renders smoothly at 60 frames per second. When I view the scene on my external monitor in full screen, the frame rate drops considerably and becomes very choppy.

The native resolution of my display is 4K and it's running at 60Hz. My iGPU is an Iris Plus 640. I'm using DPI scaling and Chrome detects a resolution of 2560x1440 with pixel ratio 2. I'm setting the canvas size to 1280x720 and this is static irrespective of its presentation size. I'm using CSS to scale it up to full screen with a 16:9 aspect ratio using these rules:

```css
canvas {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 56.25vw;
    max-width: 177.78vh;
    max-height: 100vh;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; bottom: 0;
    left: 0; right: 0;
    -ms-interpolation-mode: nearest-neighbor;
    image-rendering: crisp-edges;
    image-rendering: pixelated;
}
```

I'm setting `image-rendering: pixelated` because I noticed a small performance and visual improvement. My understanding is that the final step of rendering is to copy the frame buffer to the visible canvas. If the canvas is larger then it interpolates in-between pixels and this has a cost. Setting 'pixelated' is a bit like using NEAREST filtering and is therefore faster.

When I create the WebGL context I'm disabling things I don't need:

```js
canvas.getContext('webgl', {
  alpha: false,
  depth: false,
  stencil: false,
  antialias: false,
  powerPreference: 'high-performance',
});
```

I've followed most of the advice [here](https://emscripten.org/docs/optimizing/Optimizing-WebGL.html). I'm using instancing with a texture atlas, I've tried to minimise state changes. Attribute 0 is enabled, etc.

I don't think the problem is in my shader since I'm rendering at a fixed size of 1280x720. Therefore, if I had too much overdraw, for example, shouldn't that also affect the performance on a smaller canvas size (like on my MacBook Pro's display)?

I'm really not sure what else to try. I've scoured the web and tried many things like using CSS transforms to scale the canvas instead of width / height. I've tried setting the `zoom` property. I've also spent a while looking through the performance tab in Chrome and (tried) to go through `about:tracing`. I've seen a few bug reports specifically about Chrome but I see the same problem in both Firefox and Safari. Have I just reached the limit of how large a WebGL canvas can be (for my GPU)?

I'm sure I've seen other WebGL demos that upscale fine to full screen so I'm really confused. What's going on?

Comment: How is your external monitor connected?

Comment: USB-C straight into the back of the monitor. It's an LG 27UK850.

Comment: Does the devtools profiler report longer frame times?

Comment: Yes: [screenshot](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tuzz/tuzz.tech/gh-pages/webgl-demo/performance.png), [performance profile](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tuzz/tuzz.tech/gh-pages/webgl-demo/performance.json) (can be loaded into Chrome)

Comment: If you go to "Apple->About This Mac" and then pick "System Report" and then under "Graphics/Displays" what does "Connection Type" say for the external monitor

Note: I'm going off [this](https://www.bigmessowires.com/2019/05/19/explaining-4k-60hz-video-through-usb-c-hub/). There are at least 5 ways for a monitor to work over that USB-C cable. Some are faster than others. Also what does "rendering at a fixed size" mean? The fastest would for your situation should be `<canvas width="1280" height="720" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></canvas>` or equiv (width: 100vw) etc...

Comment: And also use `alpha: false` when creating the context. That said, which Macbook Pro? I suspect any of the Intel GPU only MacBook Pros will have trouble drawing much at 60fps at 4k. Basically I'd try not even using WebGL, just make a fullscreen div and change it's background color and see if it runs fast.

Comment: "Connection Type" is "Thunderbolt/DisplayPort" ([screenshot](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tuzz/tuzz.tech/gh-pages/webgl-demo/graphics.png)). By "fixed size" I (think) I mean the same as you describe. I set the canvas size (with JavaScript) to 1280 by 720 and don't change it. If you inspect element in the demo you can see those attributes set on the canvas.

Comment: I'm setting `alpha: false` when I get the context (see the second code block above). Regarding "will have trouble drawing much at 60fps at 4k" - do you think it's the final step(?) in rendering that's the problem, when Chrome copies the framebuffer to the visible canvas? I don't really understand that bit well.

Comment: I'll try making a div color changer and see if that runs smoothly at 60fps.

Comment: I made a color changer ([here](https://tuzz.tech/webgl-demo/color-changer)). It prints the average fps over the last 10 frames and weirdly it says it's running at 60fps but at full screen it's definitely dropping frames. Weirdly it seems to alternate between ~13ms for a frame and ~20ms (see [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tuzz/tuzz.tech/gh-pages/webgl-demo/alternating.png)). I guess the iGPU just isn't up to the task which is disappointing.

Comment: It seems incredibly wasteful to render at 1280x720, have that scaled up to 5K by Mac OS, then that's scaled down to 4K by DPI scaling, assuming that's what it's doing. It would be nice if Chrome could bypass this double scaling operation but I guess that's not under its control.